# Why is this sqlite3 insert statement not adding a row?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, cgi

I have a table, skills, which is presently empty despite my attempts to add rows to it. I have the following Python code in a CGI script:

```
open('/tmp/skills', 'a').write('Reached 1!\n')
if get_cgi('nous2dianoia'):
    open('/tmp/skills', 'a').write('Reached 2!\n')
    #if (get_cgi('previous') and get_cgi('name') and get_cgi('previous') !=
      #get_cgi('name')):
        #cursor.execute('DELETE FROM skills WHERE name = ?;',
          #(get_cgi('previous'),))
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO skills (name, nous2dianoia,
      hereandnow2escapist, nf2nt, social2individual, ithou2iit,
      slow2quick) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);''',
      (get_cgi('name'), get_cgi('nous2dianoia'),
      get_cgi('hereandnow2escapist'), get_cgi('nf2nt'),
      get_cgi('social2individual'), get_cgi('ithou2iit'),
      get_cgi('slow2quick'),))
    open('/tmp/skills', 'a').write('Reached 3!\n')
```

When I load a page, /tmp/skills has a freshly appended:

```
Reached 1!
Reached 2!
Reached 3!
```

However, the table remains empty. (The rest of the script runs without crashing, and displays what one would expect to be displayed if the script were called without any CGI variables passed.)

I haven't started a transaction; the SQL operations are not particularly advanced or intricate.

Any insight on how I can get this to run without reported error, but have an empty skills table in the database?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insert statement is not automatically committed.  From the docs on [`sqlite3.Connection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects):

> `commit()`
>
> This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t
>   call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is
>   not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you
>   don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you
>   didn’t forget to call this method.

To automatically commit, [use the connection as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

```
# connection.commit() is called automatically upon exit of context manager
# unless an exception is encountered, then connection.rollback() is called.
with connection:
    connection.execute(insert_statment)
```

Comment: Thank you; will accept (should have been connection.commit()). I'd tried earlier to commit, and gotten an error.